# Libgdx | Is performance effected by creating new Timer.Task every frame?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

For my game, I have to create a new Timer.Task for each of my enemies so that I can execute a bit of code after x seconds. After the code is executed, I cancel the task. This timer is created when the player collides with the enemy. So, will it effect my performance by creating a new Timer.Task so often? Keep in mind, there are lots of enemies. If so, then is there a better way to execute a piece of code after x seconds (only 1 time). Thanks!

Comment: yes, `android.os.Handler` and its "delayed" methods

Comment: @pskink This doesn't see to be crossplatform.

Comment: Libgdx tasks are unrelated to the Android handler. The tasks are run on the GL thread.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely to be of any concern as long as you reuse your tasks so you don't cause a lot of allocations and GC in the render loop. One way to do this is with pooling. This will require concrete Task implementations, rather than anonymous ones.

You could create a base PoolTask to extend your tasks from. Instances of this will automatically be sent back to a pool in Pools when complete, instead of getting garbage collected. By the way, there's no need to manually cancel tasks when they complete, since Timer already does this automatically.

```
public abstract class PoolTask extends Timer.Task {
    public void run (){
        doTask();
        Pools.free(this);
    }

    abstract public void doTask();
}
```

You can implement subclasses of this by putting your actions into the `doTask()` method instead of `run()`. Your subclass must have an empty constructor, so you can get pooled instances automatically from Pools.

```
MyPoolTaskSubclass someTask = Pools.obtain(MyPoolTaskSubclass.class);
someTask.configure(x, y, z); //you can add config methods if it needs parameters
                             //since the constructor must be empty

Timer.scheduleTask(someTask, someDelay);
```

If your task needs parameters and some of them need to have default values, the class should implement Poolable and reapply the defaults in the `reset()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that way, it's not performance wise, there's a much simple way to archive what you want, inside your enemy render method just add the following:

```
private float timeSeconds = 0f;
private float period = 1f;

public void render() {
    [...]
        timeSeconds +=Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();
                if(timeSeconds > period){
                    timeSeconds-=period;
                    handleEvent();
                }
    [...]
}
```

you can create a generic class to use this "timer" in different places, but i leave that to you.

ps: put an extra condition to it if you don't want it to repeat.